# PowerShell execute exe show nothing

Tags: sql, powershell, command-prompt

I have a PowerShell script that run .exe from command prompt with argument parameter.
When I run the .exe fromcommand from command promp it working well and the .exe insert some rows in DB

```
C:\NF\debug>CMExecuter.exe abc.rpr
```

When I try to run the same command from PowerShell , nothing happen . There is neither error appeared nor rows inserted in DB .please help me as I am confused

I tried the both commands from Powershell and both showed nothing .

**solution :1**

```
  & "C:\NF\debug\CMExecuter.exe" "abc.rpr"
```

**solution :2**

```
 Start-Process -FilePath "C:\NF\debug\CMExecuter.exe" -ArgumentList "abc.rpr"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your command prompt and powershell has different rights?
Please test this the following way: if your command executes well from a command prompt, start the powershell from that command prompt (by typing powershell and enter) and test your ps command from that powershell.

Comment: Thanks @placa . When I run PS from command prompt , exe executed and records added to DB . so what that means ?and how I use that to resolve the issue I faced .

Comment: It is possible that your command promp starts as administrator by default, so try to start the powershell also as admin (right click and "Run as Admin"). Also there is a way to detect in powershell if you have the admin rights: ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator") if this returns true, then you have admin rights, if not, then no.